# Cut the Apostrophe (') with cut or awk

Tags: grep, cut

I'm trying to cut a line of asterisk output.
The complete line:

```
[2017-11-01 08:23:58] NOTICE[13443]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:659 log_failed_request: Request 'INVITE' from '"66666" <sip:66666@192.168.1.248>' failed for '163.172.107.10:5070' (callid: f64a37f3cc5a88f4cd957ecb7b65a14f) - No matching endpoint found
```

I need to see only this 163.172.107.10 in my output
So my command is this:

```
cat test | grep endpoint | awk '{print $13}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
```

My output:

```
'163.172.107.10
```

But I can't get rid of the ' (Apostrophe)
I tried: cut -d '''
But that didn't work
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and lemme know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

If this line follows a similar patters as pointed above, then

try this

```
gawk -F"'" '{print $6}' | cut -d":" -f1
```

as in

```
echo "[2017-11-01 08:23:58] NOTICE[13443]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:659 log_failed_request: Request 'INVITE' from '"66666" <sip:66666@192.168.1.248>' failed for '163.172.107.10:5070' (callid: f64a37f3cc5a88f4cd957ecb7b65a14f) - No matching endpoint found" | gawk -F"'" '{print $6}' | cut -d":" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the below helps.

```
cat test | grep endpoint | awk '{print $13}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | tr -d "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/.*failed for \047/,"");sub(/:.*/,"");print}'  Input_file
```